# Case ... When with strings in mysql

Tags: sql, case, varchar

Hi I want to have some query like

```
Select 
 case column1
  when column2 like '%Test%' then column 3
  else 0
 end
FROM myTable
```

in column2 there are varchars stored. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: there's not much logic written in your example.

Comment: You should try and expalin the logic you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't make much sense.
Why do you do a case on column1 but completely ignore that value afterwards?
Did you just copy and (w)paste that into your query?

Anyways, this is what I would expect to work in any of the ordinary RDBMS':

```
case
  when colum2 like ...then
    3
  else
    0
  end as abc
```

However, the only thing I know of mySQL is that it usually does everything different than your average Joe RDMS would do them.

Comment: this was simply an example but your answer fits my needs, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like...

```
Select column3 from myTable where column2 like '%Test%'  
union all  
select 0 from myTable where column2 not like '%Test%'
```

Note that the "not like" operator can be slow